# How to classify mixed data?

Tags: classification, svm, naive-bayes, mixed-type-data

I am trying to do some classification tasks on mixed data set (Hepatitis data set)from UCI ,I will apply SVM and Naive Bayes in R & WEKA, both of them can not handle mixed data directly. Naive Bayes  for example deals with categorical data only, in this case I need to convert numerical to nominal for Naive Bayes ,or dummy the variables for SVM,  I am not sure  if I am dong the correct steps or no , **does any body has any  idea  how can the two algorithms  deal with such data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For categorical attributes, we need some coding scheme to convert **data frame** to **data matrix**. Here is a good reference on coding schemes.

[R LIBRARY CONTRAST CODING SYSTEMS FOR CATEGORICAL VARIABLES](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/)

In R, we can easily do it by `model.matrix` function. Here is an example on IRIS data

```
> head(model.matrix(~.,iris))
  (Intercept) Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Speciesversicolor Speciesvirginica
1           1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2                 0                0
2           1          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2                 0                0
3           1          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2                 0                0
4           1          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2                 0                0
5           1          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2                 0                0
6           1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4                 0                0
```